# (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null at main.js:21)

Tags: javascript

```js
function f1() {
 var num, out;

 num = document.getElementById('mynum').value;
 out = document.getElementById('out');

 if (num == prNum) {
  out.innerHTML = "Вы угадали";
 }
 else if (num > prNum) {
  out.innerHTML = "Загаданое число меньше";
 }
 else {
  out.innerHTML = "Загаданое число больше"
 }
}

var prNum, tempOut;
prNum = Math.floor( (Math.random() * 10) + 2);
tempOut = document.getElementById('temp-out');
tempOut.innerHTML += prNum;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Game</title>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Введите число: <input type="text" id="mynum"></p>
 <button onclick="f1()">Угадать</button>
 <hr>
 <p id="out"></p>
 <p id="temp-out"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Нашел в чем ошибка. В HTML: `<script src="main.js"></script>`, нужно добавить `defer`,чтобы JS загрузился после HTML: `<script src="main.js" defer></script>`